# Website design / where to put simple links

Tags: website-design, layout

i am developping a website with this exact same layout
http://demo.nicethemes.com/paeon/

i have several pages like services/contact/faq .. etc wich fit perfectly with this design

but i have also some simple pages like :
links : contains about 5 simple links
news : contains about 10 simple lines
downloads : contain only 1 file to downloads

the last page is the more problematic, because i have a big blank page with a simple link to download .

so any idea on where i can put these simple items ?

Comment: one idea , that would be intersting, is to make a mega menu , with items directlly on the menu,  what do you think ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you were to have a page called "Resources" and on that page you had sections for News, Links and Downloads? Sounds like these three sparse pages can be combined in a way that would make sense. This would also reduce the number of links in the navigation.

Part of determining the information architecture is smart grouping and deciding what items are siblings and what are children. If you wind up with a page that has a single link in it that indicates it is likely a child rather than a sibling.

Comment: finally i  have chosen the megamenu option , because the news/links/downloads labels have to be visible in the front page. ,and make the menu less empty . i really appreciate your answers guys . thanks a lot .

Comment: after testing this, i have "really" finally chosen your solution about one page containing resources :)

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how these sections are important for users.

In case Links and Download(s) are not supposed to be used that frequently, and you don't need to emphasize their presence, the quickest way would be to put them in the footer.

For News section I would either prepare a new subpage and design it wisely (including some graphics, appropriate typography, etc.) so they would take more space, or find some place within the Home page (exact position depending on how important these News are).

Comment: i agree with the news page, but for the links and downloads i think that it's better to leave them on the top and use mega menu style, because they are more visible, and the menu look less empty .. still thinking and experimenting .